# Are free dynos using SSL/TLS connection?

Tags: ssl, heroku, tls1.2

I am using the free dyno plan from heroku and I am a bit confused because in the documentation, it says:

> Heroku automatically manages TLS certificates for apps running on paid dynos on the Common Runtime.

(see: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/understanding-ssl-on-heroku)

This seems to imply that free dynos do not come with a SSL/TLS connection, however, the domain of my app does start with https. Hence I am confused; is my connection to my heroku app SSL encrypted or not?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Wow! I know this is late and you probably figured this out by now, but for anyone else that comes across this looking for answers:

The way I've seen Heroku work is:

- Heroku only provides SSL certificates for paid dynos
- For free dynos you have the option to include SSL as a paid add-on (pricing for those start around $14/month) - my personal opinion is that a paid dyno ($7/month) seems more cost effective, but your particular case may vary. In any case, do a cost analysis to see what works for you.

(This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56155448/any-way-to-add-a-free-ssl-certificate-on-a-free-heroku-dyno?rq=1) may (as I understand it) help you set up SSL with a certificate that you already own.)

Generally, as I understand it, without an SSL certificate, just having https on your domain won't really do anything. It may just use the regular http version as a fallback.

#### Edit:

I think I may have misunderstood your question - I think the `https` on your domain is because you may be using a `herokuapp.com` domain, which is provided by Heroku for free.

The bit you quoted from Heroku's docs is talking mainly about providing SSL on custom domains. Hope that helps!