# Any way to add a free SSL certificate on a free heroku dyno?

Tags: ssl, heroku, dns, ssl-certificate

I've got a heroku free plan, which is running on a custom domain with the PointDNS add-on so it can provide nameservers for DNS provider, if that matters.

I've got the website up and running on my custom domain, on https, but the ssl certificate points to *.herokuapp.com.

I suppose I need another SSL certificate for my custom domain, but after looking around for a long while I still couldn't find anything that doesn't require a paid heroku plan.

Is it even possible to add an ssl certificate, on a free heroku plan, on a custom domain? If so, please help me out.

I'm really over my head here and my knowledge about anything-ssl or dns is very limited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the PointDNS add-on doc (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pointdns), I don't see how you can do this easily.

But, if you have purchased the domain (and not ddns), this should be pretty easy with cloudflare.

[Setting up a Custom Domain name and FREE SSL certificate for Heroku Apps](https://dev.to/densityx/setting-up-a-custom-domain-name-and-free-ssl-certificate-for-heroku-apps-2063)

1. Add DNS record to point to your site and redirect to heroku.
2. Enable the Crypto certificate, after this the certificate will be automatically distributed by Cloudflare.

Comment: Sadly (NOW):"When an app is migrated to the new infrastructure, its default appname.herokuapp.com, DNS records, and any haiku.herokudns.com custom domain records are modified to point to the IP addresses of the new routing infrastructure. For a period of 24-48 hours, the app is accessible via both the new and old routing infrastructure. When the migration completes, the app will no longer be accessible via the old routing infrastructure and all traffic must flow via the new infrastructure. Requests for an app sent to the old infrastructure will result in error code: H31 Misdirected Request."